# How to convert a string to a unique number?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like this:

```
// viewed
+----+------------------+
| id |  username_or_ip  |
+----+------------------+
```

As you see, `username_or_ip` columns keeps `username` or `ip`. And its type is `INT(11) UNSIGNED`. I store IP like this:

```
INSERT table(ip) VALUES (INET_ATON('192.168.0.1'));

// It will be saved like this: ip = 3232235521
```

Well, I want to know, is there any approach for converting a string like `Sajad` to a unique number? *(because as I said, `username_or_ip` just accepts digit values)*

Comment: Why do you save `Ip` as a int ? Especially if you mix it with `Username` a varchar will be more suitable, but more recommended to put `ip` and `username` in different columns both as `varchar`.

Comment: @OrelEraki Well, what is your offer? Using `VARCHAR (50)` type?

Comment: As much as you want to limit the username length of your project.

Comment: @OrelEraki Alright, using of a `VARCHAR` type for that column is a solution. But still I like to convert username and store it as `INT`, Because a *integer* columns is much faster that a *varchar* column. But if I did not find a solution, I will go with *varchar* type. Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int(11)` is a 32-bit data type. As such it's just enough to hold an ipv4 address. Your question points that out.

To *reversibly* convert an arbitary string to a 32-bit data type is difficult: it simply lacks the information storage capacity.

You could use a lookup table for the purpose. Many languages, including php 5.4+, support that using an process called "interning." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning

Or you could build yourself a lookup table in a MySQL table. Its columns would be an `id` column and a `value` column. You'd *intern* each new text string by creating row for it with a unique `id` value, then use that value.

Your intuition about the slowness of looking up `varchar(255)` or similar values in MySQL is reasonable. But, with respect, it is not correct. Properly indexed, tables with that kind of data in them are very fast to search.

Comment: Oh really?! So, if the speed of looking up in a `varchar` or `int` column is the same, well, just I will use `varchar` simply!!

Comment: The speed is not the same. Obviously there is more data in a string. But the whole point of using a DBMS like MySQL is to put the burden doing such lookups onto somebody else, so you can get your application built in reasonable time. The people implementing MySQL have made string lookups very fast.